# How to add a new HDD in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

How can I add a 2nd HDD to my Ubuntu 16.04

**Here is my  FSTAB**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/wagedata--vg-root /   ext4    errors=remount-ro 0      1

# /boot was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=2fabd94d-0e1c-4f78-bed5-64fc35b711ea /boot   ext2   defaults   0   2

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=BC1B-47F9  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077    0      1
/dev/mapper/wagedata--vg-swap_1 none   swap    sw     0      0
```

When I run  `sudo blkid` I see bellow code

```
root@wagedata:/home/rabbani# sudo blkid
/dev/sdb1: UUID="BC1B-47F9" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="3e2c33a8-6b21-421c-88ae-c02b45832f25"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="2fabd94d-0e1c-4f78-bed5-64fc35b711ea" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="1791ed17-9592-491f-98d7-59200354e0d7"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="94LT0V-Wrye-Rl9A-QLnr-uYT9-ngoF-Ae92vU" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="58282528-5179-4157-a789-e5b63e23d94d"
/dev/mapper/wagedata--vg-root: UUID="dc8296fa-0527-4c17-acc6-14e38472acab" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/wagedata--vg-swap_1: UUID="9175a4d8-8fe5-4ef2-803e-e7648dd40898" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda: PTUUID="514c954f" PTTYPE="dos"
```

Here `/dev/sda: PTUUID="514c954f" PTTYPE="dos"` might be my new HDD

and here is the result of `fdisk -l`

```
root@wagedata:/home/rabbani# sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x514c954f

Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 424B06DE-0537-4C74-9BEB-AC001CEFD96F

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624   2050047    999424   488M Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  2050048 976771071 974721024 464.8G Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/wagedata--vg-root: 85.2 GiB, 91486158848 bytes, 178683904 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/wagedata--vg-swap_1: 7.9 GiB, 8510242816 bytes, 16621568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

**My New Disk is (1TB) so How I can create a directory and add this HDD**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x514c954f
```

Comment: You need command to format and mount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall gparted
```

In gparted select the drive `Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors`

Creates a new msdos partition table.

In unallocated space, create an ext4 file system partition.

Apply the changes and close gparted to continue running:

```
blkid /dev/sda1
```

This command will give you a output similar to this:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="1532e85b-0337-412d-9644-ef6ad282efdb" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ab6eab6e-01"
```

Write down the UUID, and continue running:

```
mkdir /media/data  *--- Change this directory as you wish*
nano etc/fstab
```

In the open file add these lines:

```
# /media/data was on /dev/sda1
UUID=1532e85b-0337-412d-9644-ef6ad282efdb /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> Save file

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Close nano

Continue running:

```
mount -a
chmod -Rf 777 /media/data
exit
```

This is all. Your disk should be mounted and ready to use.

*Remember to change /media/data by as you wish*

Comment: `Creates a new msdos partition table.

In unallocated space, create an ext4 file system partition.

Apply the changes and close gparted to continue running:` please add this command in your answer

Comment: strange that this was accepted because this is how you add a root disk, not a 2nd disk

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you intend to use it. I have an extra hard disk drive with a **data** partition, where I keep my own data (instead of in the home directory). This makes it very straightforward to separate the backup of the system from the backup of my own data (documents, own program code, pictures, music, video clips etc).

It is not necessary to have this partition in fstab, but I have it there, because it is convenient. It will always be mounted (unless I unmount it). Earlier I dual booted with Windows, so I had the NTFS file system, but now I have an ext file system since several years. It has an ext3 file system, but if I would make it now, I would use the **ext4** file system. This is the corresponding line in fstab:

```
UUID=d3f3e5a3-3deb-4e43-8e1a-c2f0de792f90 /media/multimed-2     ext3    defaults 0       2
```

People recommend to create a mountpoint in the /mnt directory, for example

**/mnt/data** (instead of /media/multimed-2, which I use for historical reasons).

-o-

Another common way to use a second drive is the create a **home** partition, copy (move) the content of your home directory to it and mount it as /home (in fstab).

-o-

***Edit:*** I suggest that you use ***gparted*** to create one or more partitions with suitable file systems.