# I don't want Ubuntu to treat HDD as a removable storage

Tags: hard-drive, nautilus

I installed Ubuntu Linux in a laptop which has both SSD and HDD. I installed it in an SSD. But HDD, I want to leave empty. When I check for the HDD installed, I found that it is treated like a removable storage even it is installed right in the laptop.

[image]

I don't want Ubuntu to treat HDD like a removable storage. I also don't want dual-booting.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think you solve the problem, if you mount the HDD via a line in the file `/etc/fstab`. See this link [How to add a new HDD in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852681/how-to-add-a-new-hdd-in-ubuntu-16-04/852703#852703)

Comment: You need one line in `/etc/fstab` for each partition that you want to mount automatically. Maybe you don't want to mount the EFI partition, and in that case it is enough to mount the `ext4` partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can permanently mount the partition on your HDD by putting it in `fstab`.

You will need a bit of information to do that.  After mounting your HDD as removable storage, find the partition's UUID by opening a terminal and typing `sudo blkid` (enter your password when asked).  This will return lines like this:

`/dev/sda6: LABEL="A Label" UUID="1e257c3b-a275-4b87-b6dc-bbfb945b8e5c" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="55d4f90c-6da8-4650-aa37-744c0a338f2d`

Find the partition for your HDD and make a **careful** note of its UUID.

If your partition's type is not ext4, stop here and leave me a comment!

In the same terminal window, type

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab-backup
```

This backs up the critical file you are about to update!  Then type `sudo mkdir /media/myHDD` (change the directory name if you like)

Then, using the text editor of your choice, edit `/etc/fstab` (root privilege required).  Insert a line like this:

```
UUID=[that thing you made a careful note of] /media/myHDD ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Save your work and exit the editor. Then open a terminal and type `sudo mount -a`.  If all went well, the HDD will be mounted through `fstab`.  If you get error messages, don't reboot your PC until you have 1) restored the `fstab` backup or 2) figured them out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have checked the HDD. There are 2 partition in it, one is EFI System partition type and FAT32, the other, which has 900 GB +, is Linux File System and Ext4 (version 1.0)

Comment: I think you want to mount the 900G partition in fstab. I'm a little troubled by the EFI partition, hopefully that is from some previous install.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried the way you gave me. No error showed up. What's next?

Comment: As long as your partition is mounted after you do the sudo mount -a and shows up in your file manager as a permanent drive, you are done.  Next reboot it should be there automatically.